# Does Delphi allow construction of a 'ShowMessage then Exit' macro?

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to have some kind of language construct to exit from a procedure and at the same time display a message? Let's call this construct 'ExitMsg'.

Something like this:

```
if WEnd= True
then ExitMsg('You have reached the end of the world!');
```

To make myself clear: I don't want ExitMsg to return a string but to show a message dialog box, then exit current procedure.

There is anything similar in other programming languages??

Comment: Sounds like you want to raise an exception...

Comment: There is a huge difference in calling Exit or raising an exception. The exception will skip any following code even in the calling procedures until the next except or finally (which can be inside EurekaLog). An Exit will only leave the current method and keep executing the following code in the calling methods.

Comment: To your question update: *"Have you ever used this construct ?"*. Yes, I did. And you know what I did ? I switched to exceptions :)

Comment: Altar, @TLama has a very important point: You used the word "error". And that word is very significant. If you implement procedure `A` and discover there is an error then procedure `A` cannot do its job ***properly***. Now the most common mistake in ***error*** handling is to think only 1 level deep. "User clicks a button which calls `A` and I want to tell the user about the error and then exit. The user can fix the mistake and try again." The problem here is that you're working on the _assumption_ that `A` is only ever called from a button click. Now you write `B` that calls `A`. (cont...)

Comment: (..cont) `A` detects an error and cannot complete ***all*** it's work. But if you don't raise an exception, `B` ***incorrectly*** thinks `A` was successful, and carries on processing and doing things ***it should not be doing***.

Comment: @CraigYoung ------------ My question title is "Does Delphi allow construction of a 'ShowMessage then Exit' macro" and not "How to implement an error handling system"

Comment: @whosrdaddy - Would you rise an exception in your program because the user forgot to enter some data in the GUI? Think about Firefox (fro example). Leave the Address Bar empty and then press the Navigate button to navigate to an empty URL. You won't see big sparkles and error messages. The world will not shake and tremble because such a small user 'error'.

Comment: Firefox does not show a message either, when you leave the address bar empty and try to navigate.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz-EXACTLY. No error raised. The user won't be 'punished' with an exception and the Firefox will not end its execution just because the user made such a small error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have some kind of language construct to exit from a function/procedure and at the same time display a message?

No.

If you wish to show a message, and exit from the function, you need to perform those two tasks separately.

Comment: Not entirely true, you could show a dialog which returns a string and exit with the result as soon as it's closed.

Comment: Nope. I think my statement is accurate.

Comment: Well obviously showing a message, dialog, exception etc will freeze the rest of your application unless you force it to another thread (not even sure if thats possible) but exiting right away wouldn't be usefull in any way. My guess is that he wanted a dialog and use that result in an exit. But maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: "To make myself very clear: I don't want EXIT to return a string (this is why I used a procedure and not a function) but to show a message dialog box"

Comment: @Altar Aahh.. Took a while but I get you now.

Comment: It is just a simple 'ShowMessage then Exit' macro. You can construct almost anything in Delphi but this (because of Exit).